# Pytube how to add a progress bar?

Tags: python, pytube

I don't know how to do it and whenever i try solutions from other topics about this question i get errors.
Mostly "TypeError: show_progress_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bytes_remaining'".

```
from pytube import YouTube

#took this def from another topic
def progress_function(stream, chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    percent = round((1-bytes_remaining/video.filesize)*100)

    if( percent%10 == 0):
        print(percent, 'done...')



url = "Any youtube url"

yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progress_function)

yt.streams[0].download()
```

for example when i run this exact code it gives me that error.

I really can't comprehend its logic. I also searched the docs from pytube3 website but i can't solve this. Pls help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use something like this: `def progress_test(*argv): print(argv)` for debugging.

Comment: it sounds like it's passing 3 parameters to your function instead of 4, this will prove how many parameters it's passing to your custom progress function.

Comment: it gives error about 4th argument which is "bytes_remaining"

Comment: Can you remove that argument then?

Comment: Actually yes when i removed it the other arguments printed without an error. Thanks for this technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `stream` then it will work, recently I tried to develop similar logic facing a similar error.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
def progress(chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    global filesize
    remaining = (100 * bytes_remaining) / filesize
    step = 100 - int(remaining)
    print("Completed:", step) # show the percentage of completed download
```

The filesize can be retrived, once you select which video or audio to download such as

```
yt = YouTube(str(link), on_progress_callback=progress) # Declare YouTube
yt1 = yt.streams.get_by_itag(int(itag)) # itag is given when you list all the streams of a youtube video
filesize = yt1.filesize
```

Hope this helps!